# Nitro OBD2 SCAM OR WORK?

Tags: obd-ii

I was looking into general car stuff like storage and lights the general stuff. I ran into a device called a "nitro OBD2" they have one to save fuel one to generate more power and stuff. Looking into them more I see many mixed reviews from general people no big car guru's (that I have found), some fun youtube videos to watch.. But my question is do things like this really do anything or are they a scam?

Comment: I don't have any hard evidence, but will tell you the "plug-n-play" devices in general are completely bogus. [Mighty Car Mods](https://youtu.be/VGtImIP6j3A) did a video on one of these type modules. You may get a kick out of it. Basically, though, there is no way for a plug in module to do what they claim it will do. Remapping the fuel table requires actually doing something with the fuel tables. You have to rewrite the code in the PCM (or ECU or whatever you want to call it) in order to effect change. Just consider you are paying $12 for something, which gives nothing in return.

Comment: Some cars have "piggy back" ECUs which override fuel/spark control, but I doubt they plug into the OBD2 port :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some just READ data from the OBD2 port. Others like the [DiabloSport](https://www.diablosport.com/products/intune.html) handheld tuner can modify the engine tune IF the model supports it. I have no idea if the [NitroOBD2](http://www.xcar360.com/nitrodata-chip-tuning-box-nitroobd2-tuning-tool.html) gadget does anything it claims to do. It makes my spidey sense tingle because the price is too low. Handheld tuners that work are not cheap.